# Django creating table inside the views.py

Tags: python, django

I have this code in my views.py, to create some table, how to remove the ID under the **Average** without affecting the ID next to student name?

```
students = StudentSubjectGrade.objects.filter(
    grading_Period=period).filter(
    Subjects=subject).order_by(
    'Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Grading_Categories','id'
).values('id', 'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname',
         'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname',
         'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Middle_Initial',
         'Grading_Categories',
         'Average', 'Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight')

Categories = list(cate.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))

table = []
student_name = None
table_row = None
columns = len(Categories) + 1

table_header = ['Student Names']

table_header.extend(list(cate.values('CategoryName', 'PercentageWeight')))


table.append(table_header)

for student in students:
    if not student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname'] + ' ' + \
           student[
               'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname'] == student_name:
        if not table_row is None:
            table.append(table_row)

        table_row = [None for d in range(columns)]

        student_name = student[
                           'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname'] + ' ' + \
                       student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname']
        table_row[0] = student_name

        id = student['id']
        table_row.append(id)

    table_row[Categories.index(student['Grading_Categories']) + 1] = student['Average'] * student[
        'Grading_Categories__PercentageWeight'] / 100

table.append(table_row)
```

this is the result,

[image]

How to remove the extra **ID** under **Average** header?

this is my html

```
{% for row in table|slice:"1:" %}
    <tr class="tr2update">
        <td><input type="text" value="{{ row.4 }}" name="studentname">{{ row.0 }}</td>
         <td class="tdupdate" hidden><input type="text" hidden></td>
        {% for c in row|slice:"1:" %}
            <td><input type="text" id="oldgrade" class="oldgrade" name="gradeupdate" value="{{c|floatformat:'2'}}" readonly></td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td data-id='row' id="ans"><input type='number' class='averages' step="any" name="average" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

please help me guys,  this problem is almost a week now , till now i didn't solve it

Comment: Before you append the each student record into table you must print the each student values. And also check what kind of data in student['Average'] and student['Grading_categories....'] to trace your error instead of going into templates. Try this.

Comment: i just want to remove the extra ID under the average, the ID append because of this table_row.append(id), please help me sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your `for` loop in the `template` as below...

```
{% for c in row|slice:"1:-1" %}
```

instead of

```
{% for c in row|slice:"1:" %}
```